# Jackson json provider linkedHashSet deserialization

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, jax-rs

We are using Spring rest template and jackson json provider to serialize/deserialize json. From my services i send a linkedHashSet back which gets converted to a HashSet on the client side when i receive it. Because of this I loose my insertion order of elements.
Is this the default implementation of jackson json provider for Set ? Is there any other way, so it can deserialize to proper implementation? I feel it's gonna be tricky but inputs will be highly appreciated from you guys.

Thanks

Comment: Try putting `@JsonDeserialize(as=LinkedHashSet.class)` on the setter?  Also, if it is relevant to the correct function of the program that the set be ordered, it isn't really so great a sin to declare the field as a `LinkedHashSet` rather than a `Set`.

Comment: using @JsonDeserialize(as=LinkedHashSet.class) on the setter worked! thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can specify the concrete class for Jackson to use with the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation.  Just put:

`@JsonDeserialize(as=LinkedHashSet.class)`

On the property's setter.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you ask the result type to be: if ask data to be mapped to a `LinkedHashSet`, then JSON Array gets mapped to it. If you use a vague type like `java.lang.Object` (or `java.util.Collection`), you will get `ArrayList` for JSON Arrays.
Keep in mind that JSON is data, not objects (by default), so metadata regarding Java types you used is not passed by default. There are ways to do that, if you need it, but usually you will simply need to provide expected type.

Comment: hi
thanks for the info, so it seems HashSet is the default implementation chosen by jackson for Set collections.
I used the @JsonDeserialize(as=LinkedHashSet.class) to de-serialize it to a linkedHashset.
The issue is that in projects we tend to use interfaces like Set, List etc for collections instead of making a field, HashSet<String> myField; so I guess this problem would be faced by many.

Comment: Yes, it is the most straight-forward and efficient set. However, you can override this default easily. `SimpleModule` has `addAbstractTypeMapping` where you could pass `Set` and `LinkedHashSet`, to change defaulting to your liking.

Comment: @StaxMan I was looking for this a long time. Your comment should be the answer